# lme4 gives singularity warning for model with three-way interaction

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, random-effects

I have a nested data set specifying cells (`no`, 240 values) within experimenters (`experimenter_1_2`, 2 values), as well as treatment status for three different treatments (`cis_0_1`, 2 values; `rt_0_1`, 2 values; `dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml`, 8 values).

I am trying to fit a linear mixed model to the data:

```r
lme4::lmer(cell_tox ~ cis_0_1 * rt_0_1 * dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml + # fixed effects: 32 treatment combinations
               + (1 | experimenter_1_2 / no),                                    # random effects: 2 experimenters
           data = df)
```

But I get this error:

```
Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number 
  of observations (problems: no:experimenter_1_2)
```

I figured that for random effects you cannot have groups with only one observation (let me know if my understanding is correct), so I removed `no` from the grouping factor:

```r
lme4::lmer(cell_tox ~ cis_0_1 * rt_0_1 * dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml + # fixed effects: 32 treatment combinations
               + (1 | experimenter_1_2),                                         # random effects: 2 experimenters
           data = df)
```

But now I am getting this warning, and I'm not sure if it can be ignored:

```
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
```

I think the cause could be the three-way interactions in the formula, but cells *are* exposed to the different categories of the three treatments.  So, how should I address the warning?

Data:

```r
    structure(list(no = structure(1:240, .Label = c("1", "2", "3", 
    "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
    "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
    "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", 
    "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", 
    "49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", 
    "60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "70", 
    "71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80", "81", 
    "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91", "92", 
    "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", "101", "102", 
    "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110", "111", 
    "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", "119", "120", 
    "121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", "128", "129", 
    "130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136", "137", "138", 
    "139", "140", "141", "142", "143", "144", "145", "146", "147", 
    "148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", "155", "156", 
    "157", "158", "159", "160", "161", "162", "163", "164", "165", 
    "166", "167", "168", "169", "170", "171", "172", "173", "174", 
    "175", "176", "177", "178", "179", "180", "181", "182", "183", 
    "184", "185", "186", "187", "188", "189", "190", "191", "192", 
    "193", "194", "195", "196", "197", "198", "199", "200", "201", 
    "202", "203", "204", "205", "206", "207", "208", "209", "210", 
    "211", "212", "213", "214", "215", "216", "217", "218", "219", 
    "220", "221", "222", "223", "224", "225", "226", "227", "228", 
    "229", "230", "231", "232", "233", "234", "235", "236", "237", 
    "238", "239", "240"), class = "factor"), cancer_treatment_modality_nt_cis_rt_cis_rt = c("NT", 
    "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", 
    "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", 
    "RT", "RT", "RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", 
    "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", 
    "NT", "NT", "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", 
    "Cis", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "Cis+RT", 
    "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", 
    "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "Cis", "Cis", 
    "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", 
    "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", 
    "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", 
    "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", 
    "Cis", "Cis", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", 
    "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", 
    "Cis+RT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "Cis", 
    "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", "RT", "RT", 
    "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", 
    "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "NT", "NT", 
    "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", 
    "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", 
    "RT", "RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", 
    "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", 
    "NT", "NT", "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", 
    "Cis", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "RT", "Cis+RT", 
    "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", 
    "NT", "NT", "NT", "NT", "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", "Cis", "RT", "RT", 
    "RT", "RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT", "Cis+RT"), cis_0_1 = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor"), rt_0_1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor"), dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), .Label = c("0", 
    "1", "10", "30", "50", "70", "90", "110"), class = "factor"), 
        experimenter_1_2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
        2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "2"), class = "factor"), 
        cell_tox = c(3831, 3416.75, 2960, 3339, 4179.991, 2657.449, 
        3081.616, 3402.351, 10322.25, 11011.5, 10992.75, 11671, 9870.186, 
        11652.73, 10270.16, 13599.91, 13341.75, 13729.5, 15161.5, 
        14897, 12713.48, 14003.69, 12051.5, 11618.97, 17350.5, 17667, 
        19013.5, 17817, 14130.19, 14504.74, 15996.64, 15343.1, 2854.75, 
        2940, 3529.75, 3017.25, 3300.817, 2230.435, 2816.393, 2995.739, 
        6643.5, 7083.25, 6600.25, 8178.5, 5853.885, 6251.482, 7142.517, 
        5271.722, 9845.75, 9205.5, 9771.5, 10747.75, 8554.357, 9328.768, 
        10545.55, 10211.05, 11872, 11451.75, 11604.25, 12196.25, 
        10044.5, 11439.07, 10043.45, 12267.24, 2396, 2528.75, 3578.5, 
        2492.25, 2196.274, 2655.077, 3063.587, 2605.733, 5726.25, 
        6690, 5469.5, 7239.5, 6201.664, 5503.733, 5797.424, 5350.008, 
        9174.5, 10113.25, 9312.5, 9312, 9177.329, 8533.627, 9355.823, 
        9587.374, 11135.5, 11683.25, 9421.75, 9070.5, 10407.81, 9491.802, 
        9618.997, 10025.88, 2348.5, 2253.5, 1942, 2588, 2288.319, 
        2738.107, 2080.981, 2514.162, 4503.25, 4561.5, 4399, 4239.75, 
        3988.309, 4006.338, 4803.431, 6333.089, 8406.75, 8144.75, 
        8000.5, 7933.5, 8477.76, 7412.418, 8569.466, 7579.317, 8824, 
        8863.75, 7112.25, 8786.5, 9746.191, 8685.768, 9798.545, 9985.12, 
        2259.25, 2183.75, 2601.75, 2327, 2367.08, 3049.353, 2152.624, 
        2590.55, 3372.75, 3728.5, 3561.75, 4004, 4270.612, 4990.842, 
        4884.089, 4752.663, 8792.75, 7210.5, 7661.75, 7807, 9318.93, 
        8284.508, 8315.429, 7525.558, 8278, 7858, 8171, 7808.25, 
        9046.27, 9393.42, 9661.161, 8358.647, 2345, 2631.5, 2737.75, 
        3441, 2493.761, 2205.289, 2356.167, 2762.305, 4303.5, 3856.5, 
        3751.5, 4334.75, 4841.862, 3905.753, 4342.73, 3954.148, 8243.25, 
        7800, 7123, 8445, 8900.102, 8698.066, 8347.403, 8166.098, 
        8679.5, 8971.25, 9158.75, 7506, 8472.489, 9363.905, 9012.89, 
        9119.003, 2250.5, 2557.5, 2192.75, 3119.25, 2443.468, 2440.621, 
        1792.035, 2482.373, 3079, 3666.25, 3694, 3493, 2966.797, 
        3649.545, 4787.299, 3615.383, 7765, 7076.75, 7710, 7961.5, 
        7288.737, 8126.394, 8749.014, 8084.581, 9296, 8396, 8145.75, 
        8139.75, 8519.924, 8898.345, 8556.817, 7979.523, 2460.074, 
        2006.016, 1627.871, 2402.19, 2607.156, 2027.841, 3266.655, 
        2753.764, 9234.954, 8680.147, 8561.736, 13133.71, 8656.254, 
        9102.84, 8920.481, 11059.25)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    240L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct in that you generally can't fit a random effect if only one observation exists for each level. The singular fit after dropping the `no` term is likely due to having a random intercept with only two levels. It is recommended to have at least six levels of a factor if you want to fit random intercepts. See discussion of this here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37647/what-is-the-minimum-recommended-number-of-groups-for-a-random-effects-factor

If you look at the random effects from your model, you'll see that it can't estimate the random intercept, and it is reported as zero.

```
m1 <- lmer(cell_tox ~ cis_0_1*rt_0_1*dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml # Fixed:  32 different combinations
           + (1 | experimenter_1_2),                          # Random: 2 Experiment
           data = df)

summary(m1)
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']
Formula: cell_tox ~ cis_0_1 * rt_0_1 * dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml +      (1 | experimenter_1_2)
   Data: df

REML criterion at convergence: 3421.4

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.0311 -0.5180 -0.0499  0.4395  4.1717 

Random effects:
 Groups           Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 experimenter_1_2 (Intercept)      0     0.0   
 Residual                     599882   774.5   
Number of obs: 240, groups:  experimenter_1_2, 2

Fixed effects:
                                                          Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)                                                 3358.5      273.8  12.265
cis_0_11                                                    7815.3      387.3  20.181
rt_0_11                                                    10081.2      387.3  26.032
dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml1                      -397.9      387.3  -1.027
dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml10                     -669.0      387.3  -1.728
dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml30                    -1014.3      387.3  -2.619
dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml50                     -917.1      387.3  -2.368
dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml70                     -736.9      387.3  -1.903
dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml90                     -948.7      387.3  -2.450
dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml110                   -1234.5      474.3  -2.603
cis_0_11:rt_0_11                                           -4777.1      547.7  -8.723
cis_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml1            -4147.8      547.7  -7.574
cis_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml10           -4507.6      547.7  -8.230
cis_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml30           -5555.2      547.7 -10.143
cis_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml50           -6061.1      547.7 -11.067
cis_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml70           -6275.5      547.7 -11.459
cis_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml90           -6606.2      547.7 -12.062
cis_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml110          -7275.5      670.8 -10.847
rt_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml1             -3265.5      547.7  -5.963
rt_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml10            -3449.9      547.7  -6.299
rt_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml30            -4359.8      547.7  -7.961
rt_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml50            -4408.0      547.7  -8.049
rt_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml70            -4487.4      547.7  -8.194
rt_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml90            -4645.7      547.7  -8.483
rt_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml110           -2302.6      670.8  -3.433
cis_0_11:rt_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml1     2698.2      774.5   3.484
cis_0_11:rt_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml10    2255.5      774.5   2.912
cis_0_11:rt_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml30    3426.7      774.5   4.424
cis_0_11:rt_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml50    3480.2      774.5   4.493
cis_0_11:rt_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml70    3807.5      774.5   4.916
cis_0_11:rt_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml90    4214.3      774.5   5.441
cis_0_11:rt_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml110   3769.4      948.6   3.974

Correlation matrix not shown by default, as p = 32 > 12.
Use print(x, correlation=TRUE)  or
    vcov(x)        if you need it

optimizer (nloptwrap) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
```

As it was estimated as zero, it should be the same as a model without that term. We can instead fit a linear model with the random intercept instead included as a fixed effect. A mixed model may not be appropriate for this data.

```
m2 <- lm(cell_tox ~ cis_0_1*rt_0_1*dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml +
         experimenter_1_2,
         data = df)

summary(m2)
Call:
lm(formula = cell_tox ~ cis_0_1 * rt_0_1 * dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml + 
    experimenter_1_2, data = df)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2304.9  -415.1   -49.3   351.8  3231.1 

Coefficients:
                                                          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                                                3401.27     278.90  12.196  < 2e-16 ***
cis_0_11                                                   7815.29     387.56  20.166  < 2e-16 ***
rt_0_11                                                   10081.15     387.56  26.012  < 2e-16 ***
dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml1                     -397.88     387.56  -1.027 0.305793    
dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml10                    -669.00     387.56  -1.726 0.085805 .  
dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml30                   -1014.32     387.56  -2.617 0.009519 ** 
dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml50                    -917.10     387.56  -2.366 0.018887 *  
dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml70                    -736.92     387.56  -1.901 0.058631 .  
dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml90                    -948.71     387.56  -2.448 0.015201 *  
dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml110                  -1191.74     477.48  -2.496 0.013344 *  
experimenter_1_22                                           -85.49     103.58  -0.825 0.410109    
cis_0_11:rt_0_11                                          -4777.13     548.09  -8.716 9.37e-16 ***
cis_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml1           -4147.79     548.09  -7.568 1.23e-12 ***
cis_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml10          -4507.55     548.09  -8.224 2.15e-14 ***
cis_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml30          -5555.15     548.09 -10.136  < 2e-16 ***
cis_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml50          -6061.06     548.09 -11.059  < 2e-16 ***
cis_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml70          -6275.54     548.09 -11.450  < 2e-16 ***
cis_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml90          -6606.19     548.09 -12.053  < 2e-16 ***
cis_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml110         -7275.47     671.27 -10.838  < 2e-16 ***
rt_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml1            -3265.52     548.09  -5.958 1.08e-08 ***
rt_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml10           -3449.88     548.09  -6.294 1.81e-09 ***
rt_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml30           -4359.79     548.09  -7.955 1.16e-13 ***
rt_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml50           -4408.02     548.09  -8.043 6.70e-14 ***
rt_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml70           -4487.39     548.09  -8.187 2.71e-14 ***
rt_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml90           -4645.72     548.09  -8.476 4.36e-15 ***
rt_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml110          -2302.56     671.27  -3.430 0.000728 ***
cis_0_11:rt_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml1    2698.17     775.11   3.481 0.000609 ***
cis_0_11:rt_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml10   2255.53     775.11   2.910 0.004010 ** 
cis_0_11:rt_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml30   3426.70     775.11   4.421 1.59e-05 ***
cis_0_11:rt_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml50   3480.19     775.11   4.490 1.18e-05 ***
cis_0_11:rt_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml70   3807.49     775.11   4.912 1.83e-06 ***
cis_0_11:rt_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml90   4214.30     775.11   5.437 1.52e-07 ***
cis_0_11:rt_0_11:dex_dose_0_1_10_30_50_70_90_110_ug_ml110  3769.38     949.32   3.971 9.89e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 775.1 on 207 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9626,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9569 
F-statistic: 166.6 on 32 and 207 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking of removing `experimenter_1_2` from the model, due to the singularity message. But that would mean that I have to establish that for each treatment status, the set of values from 2 experimenters are not significantly different.? Can I clarify by including `experimenter_1_2` as a fixed effect, I am allowing for random intercepts, but if I include `(1|experimenter_1_2`), I am allowing for both random intercepts/slopes?

Comment: Including it as a fixed effect is possible, as I did above in the post. It allows you to take into account differences between the two experimenters in terms of the outcome, but you are assuming that after you take that into account, the relationship between your other variables and the outcome is the same.